# The signature of quadratic form f(x,y)=xy

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am having trouble finding the signature of $f(x,y)=xy$, since the only reasonable guess I can think of is $xy=\frac{1}{2}(x+y)^2-x^2-y^2$, but $\{(x+y),x,y\}$ is not a linearly independent set.

Comment: $$\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 1 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
2 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia

Answer (score 1):

To save your idea: polarize $f$ to get the bilinear form $$b((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)) = \frac{f(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2) -f(x_1,y_1)-f(x_2,y_2)}{2}.$$If $(e_1,e_2)$ is the standard basis of $\Bbb R^2$, compute $b(e_i,e_j)$ and get the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1/2 \\ 1/2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$The characteristic polynomial is $t^2-1/4$, so the eigenvalues are $1/2$ and $-1/2$. The index of $f$ is $1$ (one negative eigenvalue), and if the signature is the difference between the quantity of positive and negative eigenvalues, the signature is zero.

Answer (score 0):

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
2 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
 - 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
2 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 1 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
2 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
2 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
 - 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

..........

Answer (score 0):

Why guess? I suspect you know that the graph of $f(x,y)=k$ is a hyperbola, so there’s some coordinate system in which $f:(X,Y)\mapsto X^2-Y^2$. Indeed, these graphs are rotated 45° from standard position, so if you need to actually rewrite $xy$ as the sum of quadratic terms, you might try a 45° rotation.

If you’re comfortable working with matrices and their eigenvalues, the associated matrix is $$\begin{bmatrix}0&\frac12\\\frac12&0\end{bmatrix}$$ with negative determinant, so it must have one positive and one negative eigenvalue.